# I have sort of php code, in this i want to send connection variable ($conn) into another page so that i can create table for database dynamically

Tags: php, database, mysqli

```
<?php    

    $a = $_GET['host'];
    $b = $_GET['username'];
    $c = $_GET['password'];
    $d = $_GET['db_name'];
    define("localhost",$a);
    define("username",$b);
    define("password",$c);
    define("db",$d);
    $conn = mysqli_connect(localhost,username,password);
    if($conn === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // Attempt create database query execution
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE $d ";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        echo "Database demo created successfully";
        header("Location:create_table.php");    
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

In this i need to send $conn with header to send it to create_table.php page.
because i am getting details of connection from user. so i cannot include this file into create_table.php . please help to find out how can i send connection variable into another file.

Comment: `include ` your config file. here http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: u can include the connection file, y not??

Comment: Allowing a user to pass you parameter to use in a database connection **IS VERY DANGEROUS** especially as GET parameters

Comment: Connections are closed by PHP automatically when a script finishes, so there are 2 reasons that would not work. 1) you `mysqli_close($conn);` manually in your script and 2) If you didnt PHP would do it anyway.

Comment: Each script must re-make the connection. So put the connection code in an include or a class that you call in every script the requires database access

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

$server= "localhost";
$user= "root";
$pass= "";

$conn= mysqli_connection($server, $user, $pass);

if(!$conn){
echo "Database Connection Install Failed ! ".mysqli_errno() ;
}

else {
echo "Database Connection Establiseh Successfully! ";

}

?>
```